# Rackspace open cloud library Guzzle error

Tags: php, rackspace, rackspace-cloudfiles, php-opencloud

I am using [OpenCloud](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/) library for Rackspace cloud files. Is there any updated library to use for Rackspace cloud files?

The current library works OK but gives the following error on composer:

```
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.
```

I see, they have also mentioned to use [OpneStack](https://github.com/php-opencloud/openstack) library but I do not know how it will be implemented with Rackspace. Can anyone please share an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the dependency line `guzzle/guzzle` to `guzzle/guzzlehttp` in the composer.json file and run composer update.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This dependency is mentioned in Rackspace package.

Comment: No, this package gives token error. I've already mentioned this package in my question. Do you have any working example?

Comment: Oh sorry. Ehmmm, I will take a look.